# Microsoft Speech Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, grammar, lexicon

I am trying to write an application by using Microsoft in-process speech recognition engine. My application uses sometimes dictation grammar and sometimes SRGS. Obviously, I do not have any problem when I use SRGS.

Even though I use one of the best available microphone (Sennheiser ME3 with Andrea usb sound card), the recognition results are far from being acceptable. My application operates in a specific domain, there are some words and phrases which are more likely to be spoken by a user of the system. My question is, is there any way to use dictation grammar and at the same time specifying important words in the domain of application. It is a kind of partially modifying the language model of the speech recognizer, only for a list of words and phrases provided by developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1. If you have a set of unusual words, you can add words using the [ISpLexicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee450823%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface (or use the [Windows Speech Recognition Speech Dictionary](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Add-or-edit-words-in-the-Speech-Dictionary)).
2. Dictation recognition improves dramatically with context. You should call[SetDictationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar.setdictationcontext%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) as you update your recognition (and as the user changes the caret position).
3. Last, you can use the [Dictation Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b5920ef3-ff03-453f-902c-eae618987ff9&displaylang=en) to define a new dictation grammar. Only do this as a last resort, as it's a very complex process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is pretty useful and informative. Let me explain little bit more based on your suggestions. 1)Actually I do not have unusual words but i have more likely words. 2) I am already using dictation context when it is applicable, sometimes it is not possible to use. 3) I agree with you. What do you think about creating multiple grammar objects, one is default dictation grammar and one based on your third suggestion; and loading them to recognizer by modifying priority and weight of each grammar. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: @alanturing - one thing you *might* want to look at is to examine the recognition results for common misrecognitions, and if you find them, examine the alternates for that phrase and if you find the more likely alternate, commit that alternate before inserting the phrase.

Comment: @alanturing - As for managing multiple dictation grammars; IIRC, that doesn't work terribly well.  Priority & weights help, but it's still quite easy for the engine to commit too early to a particular hypothesis.  (Also, a new dictation grammar has to have most of the original dictation grammar, as users will typically still say words outside the "more likely" subset.)

Comment: @alanturing - also, what *is* your domain?  There are specialized medical and legal dictation models already [available](http://vistadictation.com).